# How to find the depth of a dictionary that contains a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary

I would like to know the depth of a dict that contains a list of dicts, I wrote a simple code but the problem is that it increment the counter of depth at each step.

this is the input that i have as an example :

```
respons = {
    "root":{
        "Flow":[{
            "Name":"BSB1",
            "Output":[{
                "Name":"BSB2",
                "Output":[{
                    "Name":"BSB5",
                    "Output":[{
                        "Name":"BSB6",
                        "Output":[{
                            "Name":"BSB8",
                            "Output":[]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "Name":"BSB7",
                        "Output":[]
                    }]
                }]
            },
            {
                "Name":"BSB3",
                "Output":[{
                    "Name":"BSB4",
                    "Output":[]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

```
def calculate_depth(flow,depth):
    depth+=1
    md = []
    if flow['Output']:
        for o in flow['Output']:
            print(o['BusinessUnit'])
            md.append(calculate_depth(o,depth))
        print(max(md))
        print(md)
        return max(md)
    else:
        return depth
        

print(calculate_depth(respons['root']['Flow'][0],0))
```

normally I want the depth of the longest branch of this dict not to go through all of the branches and increment at each step

### EDIT

The desired Outcome will be for this structure : 5
Why ?
It is the longest branche BSB1 => BSB2 => BSB5 => BSB6 => BSB8

Comment: Could you please add what is desired outcome? That is, what is the expected depth of the dictionary in the question (and ideally explain why). Also, can you edit your question to include what your code returns (and why that is not the desired outcome)?

Comment: @NikolaosChatzis I updated the question Thank you In advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the depth is of this structure is debatable. Your code (and the way you indent the data structure) seems to suggest that you don't want to count the intermediate lists as adding a level to a path. Yet if you would want to access deep data you would write

```
respons['root']['Flow'][0]['Output'][0]['Output'][0]
#                      ^^^          ^^^          ^^^ ...not a level?
```

And taking this to the leaves of this tree: is the deepest `[]` a level?

Here is code that only counts dicts as adding to the level, and only when they are not empty:

```
def calculate_depth(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, list) and len(thing):
        return 0 + max(calculate_depth(item) for item in thing)
    if isinstance(thing, dict) and len(thing):
        return 1 + max(calculate_depth(item) for item in thing.values())
    return 0
```

This prints 19 for the example data:

```
print(calculate_depth(respons['root']['Flow'][0]))
```

Adapt to your need.